# Pyodbc and AWS Lambda

Tags: python, sql, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I have a fairly simple SQL query that's taking forever to run in my Lambda function and I don't know why. I know `OR` statements can be a killer in SQL, but in my database editor, it runs in about 800ms. Why would it take longer in a Lambda function?

I'm using `cursor.execute()` and passing the SQL statement.

SQL Query:

```sql
      select * 
            from dbo.housing
            where App_date >= (select notification_date from dbo.hub_notification_log where object_name = 'HOUSING_ASSIGN')
                    or Application_Complete >= (select notification_date from dbo.hub_notification_log where object_name = 'HOUSING_ASSIGN')
                    or Application_Cancel_Date >= (select notification_date from dbo.hub_notification_log where object_name = 'HOUSING_ASSIGN')
                    or MoveIn_Date >= (select notification_date from dbo.hub_notification_log where object_name = 'HOUSING_ASSIGN')
                    or Check_Out >= (select notification_date from dbo.hub_notification_log where object_name = 'HOUSING_ASSIGN')
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if the engine/parser of the RDBMS you're using is smart enough to recognize that all of those subqueries are identical. In the event that it's not, you might try instead having just one subquery with an alias assigned to its result -- if your RDBMS allows it, in the SELECT clause, and then comparing all of the other dates to the result of that.

Comment: @mechanical_meat - That's a valid point; however, what confuses me still is that it runs in SSMS within 800 ms. I'm thinking the issue has something to do wtih pyodbc or the AWS platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with my SQL Server table `hub_notification_log`. The AWS user account querying the data could not access the table and I ended up having to create a new table with a similar structure and re-apply the permissions for the AWS user account. I'm not entirely certain what the difference was between the two tables and permissions, but it seems to work well now. Thanks @mechanical_meat for your insight and attempting to help me out. I appreciate it!